# Event emitter is called twice when scroll-up - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with the scroll-up and call new items, the scroll-up is inverted, so the idea is when the screen reaches the top it should call more items.

These are the methods

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
 onResize() {
 this.onScroll({} as Event);
}

@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event: Event) {
 const element = event.target as HTMLElement;
 const containerHeight = element.offsetHeight;
 const scrollHeight = element.scrollHeight;
 const scrollTop = element.scrollTop;

 const tolerance = 0;
 const isCloseToBottom =
   Math.abs(containerHeight - scrollHeight - scrollTop) <= tolerance;

 if (isCloseToBottom) {
  this.loadMoreMessagesEmitter.emit();
 }
}
```

However we will never know exactly the size of the window because the items can be large or can be small.

Also, this is partially working because it emits the data correctly, however it is emitted twice when I scroll-up with the mouse, if I scroll-up with the scroll-lock from the keyword is fine.

Can somebody help me out?